# Como evitar repetir código?

Tags: python

Eu tenho um script em Python 3 que tenta ser um chatbot, aonde tem vários *if* e *elses* que são usados baseados no que o usuário responde.

O problema é que em todas as funções, tipo **get_name()** ou **get_age()**, esses *if* e *else* se repetem.

```
def get_name():
while True:
    global name
    name = question_renderer("What's your name?")
    name = name.lower().capitalize()
    if name == '':
        continue
    elif name.isdigit():
        typing(1)
        print("Please don't type numbers.")
    else:
        list = ["I like your name.", "I always wanted to have that name.", "My friend has the same name."]
        typing(1)
        print(choice(list))
        break

def get_age():
while True:
    try:
        age = int(question_renderer("How old are you, {}?".format(name)))
    except ValueError:
        typing(1)
        print("Please, just type numbers.")
    else:
        if int(age) <= 25:
            typing(2)
            list = ["You're still young.", "Being young is very good.", "Enjoy your youth."]
            print(choice(list))
        elif int(age) > 25:
            typing(1)
            list = ["You're getting old already.", "I hope you have enjoyed your teenage years.", "More bills to pay than friends."]
            print(choice(list))
        break
```

Como faço para isso não acontecer em todo o código?

Comment: Por que em vez de daquele continue você não bota um if name !='': e bota o elif como if e o else dentro do primeiro if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo uma forma melhor de fazer seu código retirar esses `if`, entretanto dei uma ajeitada no seu código e tirei coisas desnecessárias.

1 - Tirei o continue, não é necessário.

2 - Você criava duas listas de frases, o tipo lista é o tipo mais lento de Estrutura de Dados, e era algo desnecessário para o Choice, logo eu criei 2 Conjuntos(Sets) e já apliquei eles dentro do Choice.

```
from random import choice

def get_name():
    while True:
        global name
        name = input("What's your name?")
        name = name.lower().capitalize()
        if name != '':
            if name.isdigit():
                print("Please don't type numbers.")
            else:
                print(choice(("I like your name.", "I always wanted to have that name.", "My friend has the same name.")))
                break

def get_age():
    while True:
        try:        
            age = int(input("How old are you, "+name+"?"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please, just type numbers.")
        else:
            if int(age) <= 25:
                print(choice(("You're still young.", "Being young is very good.", "Enjoy your youth.")))
            elif int(age) > 25:
                print(choice(("You're getting old already.", "I hope you have enjoyed your teenage years.", "More bills to pay than friends.")))
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também substituir o loop ***while*** chamando a função novamente nos lugares onde ela teoricamente não receberia o ***input desejado***.

> Estou reutlizando a o código do user92257

```
from random import choice

def get_name():
    global name
    name = input("What's your name? ")
    name = name.lower().capitalize()

    if name != '':
        if name.isdigit():
            print("Please don't type numbers.")
            get_name() # aqui

        else:
            print(choice(("I like your name.", "I always wanted to have that name.", "My friend has the same name.")))
            
def get_age():
    try:        
        age = int(input("How old are you, "+name+"? "))

    except ValueError:
        print("Please, just type numbers.")
        get_age() # E aqui também

    else:
        if int(age) <= 25:
            print(choice(("You're still young.", "Being young is very good.", "Enjoy your youth.")))

        elif int(age) > 25:
            print(choice(("You're getting old already.", "I hope you have enjoyed your teenage years.", "More bills to pay than friends.")))
```